# jQuery loading other html pages, but how to revert to original content

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have done this small piece of jQuery code to load html files into a DIV but I'm struggling to work out how i can for example place a back button on the loaded content and once clicked will revert to the original content any ideas?

Ideally i would like to use a ajax effect when loading the content with a throbber but reading up online loasd is the best way?

```
$('.load-page').on("click", function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $('#in-the-news').load(href);
  return false
});
```

link:

```
<a href="/page-to-load-into-div" class="load-page">link</a>
```

html:

```
<div id="in-the-news">
  <p>original content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to cache the original content into another object when the user presses the link, and then take it back when the user press the original link.

somethin like this (untested)

```
$('.load-page').on("click", function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  if ($('#hidden-cache').html() == ''){
      $('#hidden-cache').html($('#in-the-news').html());
  }
  $('#in-the-news').load(href);
  return false
});

$('.original-page').on("click", function() {
  $('#in-the-news').html($('#hidden-cache').html());
  return false
});


<div id="in-the-news" class="original-page">
  <p>original content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As an option, maybe store only `url`, cause page size might grow fast and user not always uses back.

Comment: Do you know how thats done? rather new to this you see plus would that work if the back button in the other files content or best to have on the same opage the original content it on

Comment: well i was thinking of placing the original content in its own file as well if that makes life easier

Comment: What @lalborno said, or create another AJAX request that will fetch the "default" page data.